# Не отображается сгенерированное изображение DOMPDF

Tags: php

Собственно, проблема: не отображается сгенерированное изображение, и не только в DOMPDF. Было использовано 4 разных способа

1. Указан путь вместо https://demo.ru/sentmail/dompdf/qr_6fa7fdbe0e5cbd16a19daf035f967356 на /sentmail/dompdf/qr_6fa7fdbe0e5cbd16a19daf035f967356.jpg
2. Указан путь до файла с помощью $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT]
3. Указан путь с помощью URL https://demo.ru/sentmail/dompdf/qr_6fa7fdbe0e5cbd1...
4. Преобразования изображения с помощью Base64 в PHP
5. Пробовал указать sentmail/dompdf/qr_6fa7fdbe0e5cbd16a19daf035f967356.jpg

Но ничего не помогло. В исходном варианте все отображается

```
<?php

$host = '1s';  // Хост, у нас все локально
$user = '1';    // Имя созданного вами пользователя
$pass = '1'; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
$db_name = '1';   // Имя базы данных
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES utf8");


$qr_id = $_GET['qr_id'];
$image = $_GET['image'];   


$check_sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `qr_id`= "'.$qr_id.'"');
while ($check = mysqli_fetch_array($check_sql)) {
        $email = $check['email'];
        $name = $check['name'];
        $phone = $check['phone'];
        $qr = $check['qr_id'];
        $promo = $check['promo'];
        $send = $check['send'];
        $ref = $check['ref'];
    }

if (!empty($promo)) {
  $check_promo = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `promo` WHERE `promo` = "'.$promo.'"');
    while ($give_kraksa = mysqli_fetch_array($check_promo)) {
      $kraska = $give_kraksa['give'];
    }
}
if (!empty($ref)) {
  $check_ref = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `ref` WHERE `ref` = "'.$ref.'"');
    while ($give_kraksa_ref = mysqli_fetch_array($check_ref)) {
      $kraska_ref = $give_kraksa_ref['kraska'];
    }
}  

      //qr code start
      include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/phpqrcode/qrlib.php';

      ob_start();
      $img = QRcode::png($qr_id, false, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 6, 2);

      $image_content = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();

      header("Content-type: text/html");

      $qr_image = base64_encode($image_content);
      $src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$qr_image;
      $src1 = str_replace(""," ",$src);
      //qr code end*/    

        $tempDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sentmail/dompdf/';
        $codeContents = $qr_id.'.jpg';
        $fileName = $qr_id.'.jpg';

        $pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
        $urlRelativeFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
            QRcode::png($qr_id, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
            echo 'Файл создан';
            echo '<hr />';

$html = '<html><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><body>';
$html .= 'Имя: '.$name.'<br>';
$html .= 'Телефон: '.$phone.'<br>';
$html .= 'E-mail: '.$email.'<br>';
if (!empty($kraska)){
    $html .=  'Бесплатных пакетов красок: '.$kraska.'<br>';
    $html .=  'Промокод: '.$promo.'<br>';
}elseif(!empty($kraska_ref)) {
    $html .=  'Бесплатных пакетов красок: '.$kraska_ref.'<br>';
    $html .=  'Реферальная ссылка:https://www.demo.fun/?ref='.$ref.'<br>';
}


    $url1 = preg_replace('!http(s)?://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/!', '/', 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sentmail/dompdf/'.$fileName.'');
    $url2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sentmail/dompdf/'.$qr_id.'.jpg';
    $url3 = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sentmail/dompdf/'.$fileName;
    $url4 = $src1;
    $url5 = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/sentmail/dompdf/'.$fileName;
    $html .=  '<img src="'.$url5.'" width="300" height="300">';
 $url6 = 'sentmail/dompdf/'.$fileName;
    $html .= '</body></html>';
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sentmail/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';              
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();// Создаем обьект
    $dompdf->load_html($html); // Загружаем в него наш html код
    $dompdf->set_Paper("A4", "portrait");
    $dompdf->render(); // Создаем из HTML PDF
    //$dompdf->stream(''.$qr_id.'.pdf'); // Выводим результат (скачивание)
    $data = $dompdf->output();
    // Сохраняем PDF файл
    echo $html;
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sentmail/'.$qr_id.'.pdf', $data);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все 6 переменных url работают,и отображают в исходном варианте,но изображения не переносится в PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно нашел исправления, просто использовал внешний генератор QR изображения
chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world&choe=UTF-8